# SDN4 - GraphRepository findOne vs findById

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am using Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0.RC1 and am noticing some interesting behavior with `GraphRepository`'s `findOne` method.

Given two `GraphRepository` extensions:

```
public interface SimpleNodeRepository extends GraphRepository<SimpleNode> {

}

public interface OtherNodeRepository extends GraphRepository<OtherNode> {

}
```

Then given a totally blank slate, say I create a single `SimpleNode` and it gets assigned an ID of 1L.  When I call `otherNodeRepository.findOne(1L)`, I get a `ClassCastException` instead of null.  This suggests to me that the `findOne` method is getting the `SimpleNode` back and is not respecting the SDN node types.

Is this expected behavior?  I think this can be worked around by creating a `findById` method in the respective repository interfaces but it seems to go against intuition and definitely seems inconsistent with say, how JPA repository handles it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't expected behaviour. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-707 to track this issue.

Please use the work around till fixed.